# Oracle (Netsuite) SQL one join limit results

Tags: sql, oracle, join, netsuite

I have an oracle SQL query and a slight problem.  I need to check if an item has a PO# that it has at least 1 line item.  The query below works however it returns a result for each line of transaction_lines and I need only une result.  PS I tried DISTINCT but get an ODBC error.

```
SELECT ITEMS.NAME, INVENTORY_NUMBER.INVENTORY_NUMBER, INVENTORY_NUMBER.ON_HAND_COUNT, ITEMS.SALESDESCRIPTION, CONDITION.LIST_ITEM_NAME,
BRAND_PARTNER.LIST_ITEM_NAME, PPROGRAM.LIST_ITEM_NAME, ENTITY.NAME, PO.TRANSACTION_NUMBER, INVENTORY_NUMBER.RECEIVED_COST, ITEMS.SALESPRICE, IR.TRANSACTION_NUMBER,
INVENTORY_SOURCE.LIST_ITEM_NAME, LOCATIONS.NAME, INVENTORY_NUMBER.RECEIPT_DATE, PO.INTERNAL_MEMO, INVENTORY_NUMBER.REFERENCE_, TEST_RESULTS.LIST_ITEM_NAME, 
INVENTORY_NUMBER.TEST_FILE_LINK, INVENTORY_NUMBER.CONNECT_TRADE_ID, INVENTORY_NUMBER.SOLD_DATE, INVENTORY_NUMBER.SOLD_PRICE, INVENTORY_NUMBER.MEMO, ITEMS.UPC_CODE, ITEMS.MPN,
ITEMS.ITEM_ID, INVENTORY_NUMBER.CLEI, INVENTORY_NUMBER.CERTIFICATION_REF_ID
FROM INVENTORY_NUMBER 
INNER JOIN ITEMS ON INVENTORY_NUMBER.ITEM_ID = ITEMS.ITEM_ID 
INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS AS PO ON INVENTORY_NUMBER.PURCHASE_ORDER_ID = PO.TRANSACTION_ID
INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS AS IR ON INVENTORY_NUMBER.ITEM_RECEIPT_ID = IR.TRANSACTION_ID
INNER JOIN TRANSACTION_LINES ON PO.TRANSACTION_ID = TRANSACTION_LINES.TRANSACTION_ID
INNER JOIN ENTITY ON TRANSACTIONS.ENTITY_ID = ENTITY.ENTITY_ID
INNER JOIN CONDITION ON INVENTORY_NUMBER.CONDITION_ID = CONDITION.LIST_ID
INNER JOIN BRAND_PARTNER ON INVENTORY_NUMBER.BRAND_PARTNER_ID = BRAND_PARTNER.LIST_ID
INNER JOIN PPROGRAM ON INVENTORY_NUMBER.PROGRAM_ID = PPROGRAM.LIST_ID
INNER JOIN INVENTORY_SOURCE ON INVENTORY_NUMBER.INVENTORY_SOURCE_ID = INVENTORY_SOURCE.LIST_ID
INNER JOIN LOCATIONS ON INVENTORY_NUMBER.LOCATION_ID = LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID
INNER JOIN TEST_RESULTS ON INVENTORY_NUMBER.TEST_RESULTS_ID = TEST_RESULTS.LIST_ID
WHERE INVENTORY_NUMBER.ON_HAND_COUNT IS NOT NULL AND ((INVENTORY_NUMBER.PURCHASE_ORDER_ID IS NULL) OR (INVENTORY_NUMBER.PURCHASE_ORDER_ID IS NOT NULL AND TRANSACTION_LINES.TRANSACTION_LINE_ID IS NOT NULL))
```

Comment: It is impossible to figure out what is going on in this query. If you removed not-important parts, it would help the people to understand the query.

Comment: It's not clear what your asking for. Can you exemplify ? What does the query returns?  What do you want ?  _if an item has a PO# that it has at least 1 line item_  is not understandable.

Comment: Sorry, this query pulls items and data related to them for a report.  The joins are just to link all the tables together.  However on the WHERE clause I need to say if the PO exists it must have a line item.  To do that I have to join the transaction_line table.  When I do that it returns a result for every transaction line item instead of just one entry for the item with the unique serial number.

Comment: Do you want one result *per item* or one result *in total*?  Could you provide an example of the result you're getting and the result you expect?

Comment: I'm looking to get one result for INVENTORY_NUMBER.INVENTORY_NUMBER is there a grouping or something I could do?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `GROUP BY` to help limit your results. You could also if you are interacting with transactions in your query you must always remember that without limiting results based on the "main line" you will receive the header record and then a record for each individual line item.

If you were doing this with a saved search you could put the criteria as "main line = true". Since I don't understand your query entirely I can't advise where to put this limitation in.

Answer (score 0):

you could also remove the join to the transaction_lines and instead of  `tl.TRANSACTION_LINE_ID IS NOT NULL` use an `exists` clause

```
and exists (select 1 from transaction lines tl 
            where tl.transaction_id = po.transaction_id)
```